# Please how can get the number of listings in a category, i have tried

Tags: python, django

I have a django app and I need to count the number of listings in a category (as defined by the models below):

**here is my complete model**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/icons/%Y/%m/%d/')

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
     
class Listing(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=False, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300)
    description = RichTextField(blank=False, null=False)
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, default=True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, default=True)
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, default=True)
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, default=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    phone_number =  models.CharField(max_length=11, default = "#")

    website =  models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, default="#")
    facebook =  models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, default="#")
    instagram =  models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, default="#")
    opening_time =  models.CharField(max_length=7)
    closing_time =  models.CharField(max_length=7)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    posted_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True)


    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

**here are my views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from listings.models import Listing
from listings.models import Category
from testimonies.models import Testimony
from our_team.models import Team_Mate
from testimonies.models import Testimony
from django.db.models import Count


def index(request):
```

**this part is working perfectly.**

```
    listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-posted_date').filter(is_published=True)[:6]
    category = request.GET.get('category')
    categories = Category.objects.all()[:7]
```

**counting listings in a category**

```
    count_cate = Category.objects.all()
    cate_count = count_cate.count()




if category == None:
    listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-posted_date').filter(is_published=True)[:6]

else:
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(Category__name=category)
```

**here is my context**

```
context ={
    'listings': listings,
    'categories': categories,
    'cate_count': cate_count,
    }

return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)
```

**Here is my html where I want the number of listings in category to show**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<!-- ======= Intro Section ======= -->
<div class="header">
<div class="header-content display-table">
<div class="table-cell">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="header-title text-light text-uppercase pb-3">Explore Bonny Island</h1>
    <h3 class="text-light">Find. Connect. Share</h3>
    <div class="search mt-3 px-0 py-1 mx-0">
      <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="GET">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center container p-0 m-0 px-1">
          <input type="text" name="keywords"
            class="form-control col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mx-2   py-4 my-2 border border-5"
            placeholder=" Keyword">
          <input type="text" name="location"
            class="form-control col-lg-3 col-md-12 mx-2   py-4 col-sm-12 my-2 border border-5"
            placeholder=" Location">
          <input type="text" name="category" value="{{ query }}" list="category"
            class="form-control col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mx-2  py-4 my-2 border border-5" 
placeholder=" Category (All)">
          <datalist id="category">
            {% for categories in categories %}
            <option>{{ categories.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </datalist>
          <button type="submit"
            class="btn search-bt col-lg-2 col-md-12 mx-2 col-sm-12 py-2 px-2 font-weight-bold my- 
2">Search</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- End Intro Section -->



<!-- ======== most popular categories ========= -->
<section class="main">
<div class="discover pb-1 m-0">
<h2>Explore Categories</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-around m-0 p-0 pt-3">
    {% for category in categories %}
    {% if category %}
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 py-2">
      <a href="{% url 'listings' %}?category={{ category.name }}" class="card category">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start px-3 m-0 py-2">
          <div class="category-name-icon p-0 m-0">
            <span class="text-dark font-weight-bold"><img class="category-icon" src="{{ 
category.icon.url }}">
              {{category.name}}</span>
          </div>
            <div class="category-list-number text-muted font-weight-bold">{{cate_count}}</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 py-2">
      <a href="{% url 'category' %}" class="card category" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
        href="#collapseExample"
        role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between = px-3 m-0 py-2">
          <i class="font-weight-bold py-1 text-secondary">More Categories...</i>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</section> <!-- ======== most popular categories end ======== -->

<!--       STRUCTURING THE POPULAR LISTINGS CONTENT-->
    <section id="popularListings" class="container mb-5 py-5">
        <!--            Popular listenings head title-->
        <div class="sectionTitle  d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
            <div class="mainTitleContents">
                <h2 class="titleText h2 text-blue">Popular Listings</h2>
                <p class="subTitleText mb-2">Explore businesses on the island.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="filterOption">
                <a href="{% url 'listings' %}"  class="btn btn-sm bg-blue">All Listings</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--           MAIN POPULAR LISTINGS ROW CONTENT-->
        <div class="popularListingsRows row py-2">
            {% if listings %}
            {% for listing in listings %}
            <div class="customCard p-1 m-0 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header p-0">
                        <div class="blank rounded" style="background-image: url('{{ 
                         listing.photo_main.url }}'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
                          background-size:cover; width:100%; height: 15em; background- 
                          position:center-top" ;></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="content-details">
                            <h3 class="m-0 mt-1 mb-2 cardTitle">{{ listing.name }}</h3>
                            <p class="cardSubTitle">
                              {%autoescape off%}
                                {{ listing.description|striptags|truncatechars:100 }}
                              {%endautoescape%}
                            </p>
                            <a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-sm bg-blue text- 
light rounded-none">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="text-dark">No listings Available</p>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>

    </section>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I make this code work as intended?

Comment: `cate_count = Listing.objects.filter(Category__name=category).count()`.

Comment: I JUST TRIED IT AM HAVE THIS ERROR 
thiserrorFieldError at / Cannot resolve keyword 'Category' into field. Choices are: category, category_id, closing_time, description, email, facebook, id, instagram, is_published, location, name, opening_time, phone_number, photo_1, photo_2, photo_3, photo_4, photo_main, posted_date, user_id, website

Comment: it's with a lowercase `c`, so `.filter(category=...)`. The same for your query in the `else:` part.

Comment: This will only work if you selected a category, so `category` is not `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the count method on the list of objects like...

```
if category == None:
    listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-posted_date').filter(is_published=True)[:6]

else:
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(category__name=category).count()
```

Please ensure where you have `Category__name=category` you must allow this to match your model field `category`.

In your `html`:

```
<!-- ======= Intro Section ======= -->
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}  
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center container p-0 m-0 px-1">
        ...
        <!--<input type="text" name="category" value="{{ query }}" list="category" class="form-control col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mx-2  py-4 my-2 border border-5" placeholder=" Category (All)">-->

        <!-- Remove value="{{ query }}" -->
        <input type="text" name="category" list="categories" class="form-control col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mx-2  py-4 my-2 border border-5" placeholder=" Category (All)">

        <!-- Should be category in categories instead of categories in categories -->
        <datalist id="categories">
            {% for category in categories %}
                <option value="{{ category.name }}"> <!-- Setting the value here... -->
            {% endfor %}
        </datalist>
        ...
    </div>       
</form>
```

Comment: when i used 
listings = Listing.objects.filter(category__name=category).count()
The was no longer there but is giving 0 and not the number of listings in that category

Comment: Where you have `category = request.GET.get('category')`... Print `category` in the console and tell me what are you seeing.

Comment: the output is None

Comment: Then that's the problem why you are getting `0` for the listings... How have you used category in your template? Maybe you should include that in your post as well.

Comment: the category is link with the Category model

Comment: please can you check the code and show me the correct way to write the code, please

Comment: I can't say whether your code is incorrect based on the limited information posted. What I want to know is where are you trying to get a `category` from when you used `request.GET.get('category')`. If you are trying to get `category`, this must be in an existing html file. I'd suggest you posting the entire `index` view and the html file that is rendering the information where you are trying to get category from.

Comment: i have updated my index, all the codes are there

Comment: I think I see the problem why it is not passing the value. Before I go ahead and update my answer, where you have `<datalist id="category">.....</datalist>` that's where you intent in trying to get the category from when you used `request.GET.get('category')` right?

Comment: No, i use that when my category was a list, i actual forgot to delete the code.
I created a category model and i post my category from admin and the category model is connected to the listing model and am trying to count the number of listing in a category
I have tried my best

Comment: I have updated the answer already... included the `html` section in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## I solved the it by calling the name of the category i want to count but am still to look for a way to count it without specifying the category name.

```
cate_count = Listing.objects.filter(category__name="Catering services").count()
```

Comment: Check my answer where I have updated the `<!-- ======= Intro Section ======= -->` form...